# Why can't I run 'pod install'?

Tags: ruby, xcode, bash, cocoapods

When I try to run `pod install` I get :

[image: output]

Though my connection is up & Github is not down.
I tried to uninstall & reinstall cocoapods but it still doesn't work. Any ideas?

Podfile :

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'App' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for Smile

  plugin 'cocoapods-wholemodule'

  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'AppUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'Firebase/Database'
  pod 'Firebase/Invites'
  pod 'Firebase/DynamicLinks'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.7.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.9.3'
  pod 'Firebase/RemoteConfig'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  pod 'Firebase/Performance'

  pod 'CryptoSwift', :git => "https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift", :branch => "swift4"

  pod 'lottie-ios'

  pod 'SwiftyGif', :git => "https://github.com/kirualex/SwiftyGif", :branch => "swift4"

end
```

I only changed 'Firebase/Crash' for Fabric & Crashlytics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing spec repo mirror might be in a bad state. Remove it to start from scratch with :

```
rm -rf ~/.cocoapods
```

Comment: I tried but after redownloading it it still throws the same error. Could it be due to another repository ?

Comment: Perhaps an issue with one of the pods in your Podfile?  Can you add the Podfile to the question

Comment: I added the podfile

Comment: I reversed the changes, ran ```pod install```it worked, then put the new libraries back into the pod file ```pod install```and it also worked. Though for some reason I am still not able to run ```pod update```or ```pod repo update```